# CiviCalendar shows nothing on Wordpress deployment

Tags: wordpress, extension

I do not see any information on my Civicalendar. When enabling backtrace and debugging I am thrown this error when the extension tries to get the JSON error:

```
Database Error Code: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND (activity_type_value.visibility_id IS NULL OR activity_visibility_value.n' at line 38, 1064
Additional Details:
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -2
    [message] => DB Error: syntax error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => 
      SELECT
        DISTINCT civicrm_activity.id AS id,
        civicrm_activity.`subject` AS title,
        civicrm_activity.`activity_date_time` AS start,
        activity_type_value.label AS activityType,
        priority_value.label AS priority,
        DATE_ADD(`activity_date_time`, INTERVAL COALESCE (`duration`, 15) MINUTE) AS `end`,
        civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id,
        contact.display_name,
        contact.contact_type,
        contact.image_URL

      FROM `civicrm_activity`

      JOIN `civicrm_activity_contact` ON civicrm_activity_contact.activity_id = civicrm_activity.id
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_case_activity` ON civicrm_case_activity.activity_id = civicrm_activity.id
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_group` AS priority_group ON priority_group.name = "priority"
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_value` AS priority_value 
        ON (priority_value.option_group_id = priority_group.id AND civicrm_activity.priority_id = priority_value.value)

      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_group` AS activity_type_group ON activity_type_group.name = "activity_type"
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_value` AS activity_type_value 
        ON (activity_type_value.option_group_id = activity_type_group.id AND civicrm_activity.activity_type_id = activity_type_value.value )

      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_group` AS activity_visibility_group ON activity_visibility_group.name = "activity_visibility"
          LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_value` AS activity_visibility_value 
        ON (activity_visibility_value.option_group_id = activity_visibility_group.id AND activity_visibility_value.value = activity_type_value.visibility_id)

      LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact AS contact
        ON contact.id = civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id
     WHERE TRUE  
      AND civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id IN (2)
      AND civicrm_activity.is_deleted = 0
      AND civicrm_activity.activity_date_time 
          BETWEEN "1970-01-01 00:00:00" 
          AND "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
      AND  civicrm_case_activity.activity_id IS NULL
     AND civicrm_activity.activity_type_id NOT IN ()  AND (activity_type_value.visibility_id IS NULL OR activity_visibility_value.name = "visibility") [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  AND (activity_type_value.visibility_id IS NULL OR activity_visibility_value.n' at line 38]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => 
      SELECT
        DISTINCT civicrm_activity.id AS id,
        civicrm_activity.`subject` AS title,
        civicrm_activity.`activity_date_time` AS start,
        activity_type_value.label AS activityType,
        priority_value.label AS priority,
        DATE_ADD(`activity_date_time`, INTERVAL COALESCE (`duration`, 15) MINUTE) AS `end`,
        civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id,
        contact.display_name,
        contact.contact_type,
        contact.image_URL

      FROM `civicrm_activity`

      JOIN `civicrm_activity_contact` ON civicrm_activity_contact.activity_id = civicrm_activity.id
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_case_activity` ON civicrm_case_activity.activity_id = civicrm_activity.id
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_group` AS priority_group ON priority_group.name = "priority"
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_value` AS priority_value 
        ON (priority_value.option_group_id = priority_group.id AND civicrm_activity.priority_id = priority_value.value)

      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_group` AS activity_type_group ON activity_type_group.name = "activity_type"
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_value` AS activity_type_value 
        ON (activity_type_value.option_group_id = activity_type_group.id AND civicrm_activity.activity_type_id = activity_type_value.value )

      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_group` AS activity_visibility_group ON activity_visibility_group.name = "activity_visibility"
          LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_value` AS activity_visibility_value 
        ON (activity_visibility_value.option_group_id = activity_visibility_group.id AND activity_visibility_value.value = activity_type_value.visibility_id)

      LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact AS contact
        ON contact.id = civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id
     WHERE TRUE  
      AND civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id IN (2)
      AND civicrm_activity.is_deleted = 0
      AND civicrm_activity.activity_date_time 
          BETWEEN "1970-01-01 00:00:00" 
          AND "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
      AND  civicrm_case_activity.activity_id IS NULL
     AND civicrm_activity.activity_type_id NOT IN ()  AND (activity_type_value.visibility_id IS NULL OR activity_visibility_value.name = "visibility") [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  AND (activity_type_value.visibility_id IS NULL OR activity_visibility_value.n' at line 38]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="
      SELECT
        DISTINCT civicrm_activity.id AS id,
        civicrm_activity.`subject` AS title,
        civicrm_activity.`activity_date_time` AS start,
        activity_type_value.label AS activityType,
        priority_value.label AS priority,
        DATE_ADD(`activity_date_time`, INTERVAL COALESCE (`duration`, 15) MINUTE) AS `end`,
        civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id,
        contact.display_name,
        contact.contact_type,
        contact.image_URL

      FROM `civicrm_activity`

      JOIN `civicrm_activity_contact` ON civicrm_activity_contact.activity_id = civicrm_activity.id
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_case_activity` ON civicrm_case_activity.activity_id = civicrm_activity.id
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_group` AS priority_group ON priority_group.name = "priority"
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_value` AS priority_value 
        ON (priority_value.option_group_id = priority_group.id AND civicrm_activity.priority_id = priority_value.value)

      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_group` AS activity_type_group ON activity_type_group.name = "activity_type"
      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_value` AS activity_type_value 
        ON (activity_type_value.option_group_id = activity_type_group.id AND civicrm_activity.activity_type_id = activity_type_value.value )

      LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_group` AS activity_visibility_group ON activity_visibility_group.name = "activity_visibility"
          LEFT JOIN `civicrm_option_value` AS activity_visibility_value 
        ON (activity_visibility_value.option_group_id = activity_visibility_group.id AND activity_visibility_value.value = activity_type_value.visibility_id)

      LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact AS contact
        ON contact.id = civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id
     WHERE TRUE  
      AND civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id IN (2)
      AND civicrm_activity.is_deleted = 0
      AND civicrm_activity.activity_date_time 
          BETWEEN "1970-01-01 00:00:00" 
          AND "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
      AND  civicrm_case_activity.activity_id IS NULL
     AND civicrm_activity.activity_type_id NOT IN ()  AND (activity_type_value.visibility_id IS NULL OR activity_visibility_value.name = "visibility") [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  AND (activity_type_value.visibility_id IS NULL OR activity_visibility_value.n' at line 38]"]
)
```

Comment: It looks like there's an activity type that it's expecting to exist in your system but it doesn't exist. (i.e. the part where it says `civicrm_activity.activity_type_id NOT IN ()` ) Did you maybe disable or delete an activity type needed by this extension?